# 60V 200mA LED strip powered with step up converter

Tags: power, led

I've got a strip of LED lights that requires a 60V supply with 200mA of draw (15w).  I am curious what would be required to get this to run off a significantly smaller voltage source (i.e. USB)  I don't believe a traditional USB charger would work as they are 5V/1A and there is no way to turn that into 15W but if I had a USB C battery pack that was able to deliver >15W is it possible to use a step up converter to power this strip?  Or a couple of 18650 batteries?

I've looked at [TI's simple switcher site](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/simple_switcher/index.html) and it is suggesting the LM2587/LM2588 as a way of turning ~5V into 60V at 200mA.   Are there more gotchas that I am missing?

The LED strip is from something like [this](https://www.earthled.com/collections/led-t8-tube-replacements-replace-your-fluorescent-t8-t10-t12-lamps-with-led/products/thinklux-led-fluorescent-replacement-tube-4-foot-18-watt-universal-t8-or-t12-ballast-compatible-dimmable?variant=20878881220).  Our office recently got an upgrade and a few fell off a truck for experimentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no gotchas. You have this figured out. All you need to do is step up the 5V supply to 60V at the required output current. If the led strip has a current regulator like a resistor, then you are done. If it requires a constant current regulator, then you also need to provide that. Or a resistor, while boosting the voltage up a bit to compensate.